# Redirect Multiple Subdomains to another domain name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, dns, subdomain

Got a question about using mod_rewrite to redirect specific subdomains to use another domain. I am looking for the shortest possible way to do this without the need to create a separate rewrite rule for each of my domain names. I will be adding many new domain names (roughly 20-30 domains total).

So let's say my main domain name is example.com and I want to use that domain name for everything. So if any of my other domains are used, they will automatically be redirected to the main domain, preserving the subdomain prefix and the URL path.

**Example:**
test.example.org => test.example.com
test2.example.co.uk => test2.example.com
test3.example.net/hello/world.php => test3.example.com/hello/world.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.([a-zA-Z]+)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1\.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am unsure if the above will work correctly or if it is proper syntax. But basically, I would like to have it match the subdomain prefix, then any domain name, and any TLD (.org, .info, .biz, .co.uk, .net, etc.). I would assume it would need to make sure that it is not the correct main domain (example.com) first to prevent a infinite redirect loop.

Also, is there a possibility to check if HTTPS is ON or OFF and set the redirect correctly? If not, I can always have HTTPS set to ON.

Sorry for this confusion, although I want to make sure I get this right the first time without needing to program each and every one of the domains into the .htaccess.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(.*) is greedy so you don't want to use that, and I assume that you don't want to recreate an infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond   %{HTTPS}s    ^..(s?)
RewriteRule   ^            -                                [E=PROTO:http%1]              

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} !^\w+\.example\.com$             [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.\w+\..+                  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^/?(.*)      %{ENV:PROTO}://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Comment: Used this example and it does work. I just need to do some further testing to ensure it will work exactly as needed. Thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: Do you understand how the first rule works the string is either ons or offs so `^..(s?)` results on %1 = "s" or "" hence the env variable PROTO get set up correctly.  Cond2A prevents a loop on `*.example.com` and cond2B files up the subdomain.  Rule2B puts it all together.  The tick would be nice if it works :-)

Comment: It works perfectly and I do understand the concept. The one issue that I am having is say someone went to example.org, it would stay at example.org until they navigate. I have tried other tricks, but I cannot get it to change to the main "example.com".

Comment: This answer works great with a couple of adjustments, you need to collect the `.*` in the last rewrite rule to be passed through to `$1` (added braces) and the `/` before `$1` was unecessary and meant that the `/` would get doubled up i.e. `example.co.uk/test -> example.com//test`. Also note, if like me you just want to redirect your .com to your .co.uk, you can replace `^(\w+)\.\w+\..+` with `^(\w+)\.example\.com$` and remove the preceding not condition.

Comment: @Steve, I've tweaked your edit.  Whilst the change is correct,  I've pulled out the / because you will get this in a system/vhost context, but it is dropped in a per-direction context (e.g. in an `.htaccess` rule).   This pattern will work in either :-)

Comment: @TerryE tidier too! `com$1` was upsetting me a little, despite it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

That rule will not work because it will redirect any host ending with `example.com` back to `example.com` and you'll get a redirect loop. You need to change the regex to look like this, to match anything that *doesn't* end with `.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)\.(?:(?!com).)*$ [NC]
```

Comment: You have definitely sorted out my mess! The only issue is, I could have other domains that have ".com" also.